# Configuring wch3 hash function in mcrouter

Tags: nosql, memcached

I came across this [page](https://github.com/facebook/mcrouter/wiki/Pools) discussing different hash functions that mcrouter can use, but could not find an example of how a hash function can be configured if you do not want to use the default ch3. In my case, i would like to use the "wch3" with a balanced (50/50) weight between two nodes in a pool. How can i manually change the default to configure wch3?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that can help you:

```
{
    "pools": {
        "cold": {
            "servers": [
                "memc_1:11211",
                "memc_2:11211"
            ]
        },
        "warm": {
            "servers": [
                "memc_11:11211",
                "memc_12:11211"
            ]
        }
    },
    "route": {
        "type": "OperationSelectorRoute",
        "operation_policies": {
            "get": {
                "type": "WarmUpRoute",
                "cold": "PoolRoute|cold",
                "warm": "PoolRoute|warm",
                "exptime": 20
            }
        },
        "default_policy": {
            "type": "AllSyncRoute",
            "children": [{
                    "type": "PoolRoute",
                    "pool": "cold",
                    "hash": {
                        "hash_func": "WeightedCh3",
                        "weights": [
                            1,
                            1
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "PoolRoute",
                    "pool": "warm",
                    "hash": {
                        "hash_func": "WeightedCh3",
                        "weights": [
                            1,
                            1
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can adjust the weight in the range [0.0, 1.0].